# Removing intersecting and internal geometry

Tags: modeling, faces, 3d-printing, knife-tool

I was trying to follow this tutorial made in Blender 2.71.x but I haven't figured out how it can be done in 2.93.x yet.   **He pulls out the self intersecting geometry**
but when I try and do it, it says **no intersections found**.

His example:

[image: img1]

My example keeps saing **no intersections found**.

[image: img2]

The video tutorial / section I'm trying to follow is.
@1:16 https://youtu.be/-rwvxusuJXU?t=81

Attached File:
[image]

Comment: could you please share your file?

Comment: @moonboots ok I attached the file.

Comment: Yes I can't fix it either, maybe someone will explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a work around fix for intersecting faces and internal geometry, this may help someone else.

**(Left to Right)**

The **1st image** is the original image with overlapping faces / edges

**The Fixes:**

The **2nd image** uses the Mesh boolean node with Union.

The **3rd image** uses an "inverse mold node"

[image: img]

[image: img2]

[image]